# How to increase the size of checkbox in WinForms?

Tags: .net, winforms

How do I increase the size of a checkbox in a .Net WinForm. I tried Height and Width but it does not increases the Box size.

Comment: Use bunifu checkbox

Comment: Only use Use bunifu checkbox if you have spare money... Probably not worth

Comment: To do this via the designer. First, change the auto size property to false. Then you can change the size as you like in the designer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The check box size is hardcoded inside Windows Forms, you cannot mess with it.  One possible workaround is to draw a check box on top of the existing one.  It is not a great solution since auto-sizing cannot work anymore as-is and text alignment is muddled, but it is serviceable.

Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form.  Adjust the size of the control so you get the desired box size and ensure it is wide enough to fit the text.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyCheckBox : CheckBox {
    public MyCheckBox() {
        this.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
    }
    public override bool AutoSize {
        get { return base.AutoSize; }
        set { base.AutoSize = false; }
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        int h = this.ClientSize.Height - 2;
        Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 1), new Size(h, h));
        ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, rc,
            this.Checked ? ButtonState.Checked : ButtonState.Normal);
    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem is that in Windows 7 the style of the checkbox don't match system default's

Comment: calling `base.OnPaint(e);` also leaves some pixels on the screen, I'd rather call `e.Graphics.Clear(this.BackColor);`

Comment: Very nice solution excepted when I make the font bigger, at each 2 font point, the right of the checkbox overlap a little bit the text at the right.

Comment: `var rc = new Rectangle(new Point(0, this.Height / 2 - h / 2), new Size(h, h));`



This allows the checkbox to be centered vertically and keep the checkbox behind it covered as well. Also you may want to limit height to around 20px depending on your use, after that it looks a bit ridiculous.

Comment: @Jader Using Clear also removes the text so you would need to custom paint that also.

Comment: I wonder what was the thinking of the WinForms development team here? What is the point in being able to modify the font size of the checkbox label if the checkbox square/tick does not reflect that change as well?

Answer (score 16):

There’s an `AutoSize` option in the `Properties` windows; if you turn that off by changing it to `False`, you will be able to modify the size of your `CheckBox`.

Comment: I'm set AutoSize to false and I'm not able change the size.

Comment: You wont have a bigger check-box, you'll only have the border of it bigger so it'll become easier to click

Comment: This will change only the size of the label attached to the checkbox, not the actual size of the square box and tick mark.

Answer (score 7):

C# version, from [a forum.codecall.net topic](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/73939-how-to-resize-a-checkbox-using-the-net-framework/) :

```
 class BigCheckBox : CheckBox
    {
        public BigCheckBox()
        {
            this.Text = "Approved";
            this.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;              
        }

        public override bool AutoSize
        {
            set { base.AutoSize = false; }
            get { return base.AutoSize; }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            this.Height = 100;
            this.Width = 200;
            int squareSide = 80;

            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 1), new Size(squareSide, squareSide));

            ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, rect, this.Checked ? ButtonState.Checked : ButtonState.Normal);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have this working, but is there a way to set the flat style?

Answer (score 3):

A simple workaround is to use the appearance property of the CheckBox. Use the following code to make the checkbox look like a button. It will function as a checkbox. Now the size can be easily changed along with the text size.

```
checkBox1.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
checkBox1.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 16);
checkBox1.AutoSize = false;
checkBox1.Size = new Size(100, 100);
```

Answer (score 3):

It support Flat

```cs
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class TodoCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    public override bool AutoSize
    {
        get => base.AutoSize;
        set => base.AutoSize = false;
    }

    public TodoCheckBox()
    {
        this.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        int h = this.ClientSize.Height - 2;
        var rc = new Rectangle(new Point(-1, this.Height / 2 - h / 2), new Size(h, h));
        if (this.FlatStyle == FlatStyle.Flat)
        {
            ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, rc, this.Checked ? ButtonState.Flat | ButtonState.Checked : ButtonState.Flat | ButtonState.Normal);
        }
        else
        {
            ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, rc, this.Checked ? ButtonState.Checked : ButtonState.Normal);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone needs VB.NET code, I adapted this code to it. I didn't fool with `AutoSize` in the class. The control should be added to the toolbox once the project is built. You can set `AutoSize` to `False` there the same as you would any other control.

If it matters, I just put the class code below the `End Class` of the form I was using it in.

To clarify what `AutoSize` does, the advantage of this new control is that the "box" portion of the checkbox can be made bigger. In the normal checkbox, you cannot change the box portion.

The only disadvantage of this new control that I see is that when you resize it the box portion overruns the text if left aligned; fix this with the `TextAlign` property.

```vb
Public Class NewCheckBox
    Inherits CheckBox

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)

        'Make the box you check 3/4 the height
        Dim boxsize As Integer = Me.Height * 0.75
        Dim rect As New Rectangle(
            New Point(0, Me.Height / 2 - boxsize / 2),
            New Size(boxsize, boxsize)
        )

        ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, rect, If(Me.Checked, ButtonState.Checked, ButtonState.Normal))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a different control (e.g. label or button) and just program the onclick event to change its appearance in an acceptable way.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a version that I use in Hi-Dpi scenarios (including per monitor), with `TableLayoutPanels` and everything configured in "automatic resize" mode (tested with .NET Framework 4.8):

```
public class AutoSizeCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    public AutoSizeCheckBox()
    {
        Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;

        // uncomment for flat style
        // FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
    }

    public override bool AutoSize { get => false; set => base.AutoSize = false; }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPaintBackground(e); // we don't use base, so we must redraw focus ourselves

        var h = ClientSize.Height;
        var w = ClientSize.Width;
        var state = Checked ? ButtonState.Checked : ButtonState.Normal;
        if (FlatStyle == FlatStyle.Flat)
        {
            state |= ButtonState.Flat;
        }

        const int focusSize = 1;
        h -= focusSize * 2;
        var rc = new Rectangle(new Point((w - h) / 2, 0), new Size(h, h));

        if (Focused)
        {
            ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Graphics, rc);
        }

        if (FlatStyle != FlatStyle.Flat)
        {
            rc.Inflate(-focusSize, -focusSize);
        }
        ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, rc, state);
    }
}
```