# winform change checkbox's color of the actual box

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there anyway to change the color of the box containing the check mark in checkbox for winform?  Something like this.

[image]

Question is to change the color of the background of the box not the check mark.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3166502/64121

Answer (score 2):

There is no a straight way to do it.

The easiest way if you necessarily have to use winforms is to mimic a Button and use images.

To do it, edit your CheckBoxes properties to the following.

- Appearance: `Normal` -> `Button`
- FlatStyle: `Standard` -> `Flat`
- FlatAppearance, BorderSize: `1` -> `0`
- FlatAppearance, All the colors: the background color of the parent container, usually is `Control`
- TextImageRelation: `Overlay` -> `ImageBeforeText`
- Image: load an image of an unchecked box

Then in the event handler CheckedChanged of each CheckBox, we change the image from an unchecked box to a checked box and viceversa, something like this:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox currentCheckBox = (sender as CheckBox);
    if (currentCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        currentCheckBox.Image = Properties.Resources._checked;
    }
    else
    {
        currentCheckBox.Image = Properties.Resources._unchecked;
    }
}
```

Or, shorter:

```
private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as CheckBox).Image = (sender as CheckBox).Checked ? Properties.Resources._checked : Properties.Resources._unchecked;
}
```

The result should be something like this:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFhHs.png)